# non-responsive grid bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to make a non-responsive grid bootstrap only for certain div?
I know there's a way to disable responsiveness by following this step [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive). But what I want is I only want the non-responsive columnn for my div.

Basically I have 3 buttons, and I want to align it using cols and I want it always fixed in 3 horizontal columns. Currently with the following code the cols will change its position responsively when the window is resized. What is the proper way of doing this other than specifying `class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4` for each class? I tried `class="col-4"`but it doesn't work. Thank you!

```
<div class="overlayOptions" ng-show=overlayOptions>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4"><a class="watchButton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4"><a class="inventoryButton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4"><a class="storeButton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Doesn't it become non-responsive when you remove col-md-4 class from those DIVs?

Comment: easy hint is to remove bootstrap ID/Class selector where the NON-reponsiveness div you wish then change into your own css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just specify only the smallest width column, i.e. the col-xs for your divs:

```
<div class="overlayOptions" ng-show=overlayOptions>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4"><a class="watchButton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"><a class="inventoryButton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></a></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"><a class="storeButton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: For BS4, there is no "xs". BS4 is a mobile first framework so you cannot specify col spans for the xs viewport, it is the default. You must instead override col spans for larger screens. BS4 would use .col-4, not .col-xs-4. If you wanted it span differently for larger VPs, you would use it like so, class="col-4 col-lg-3".